# Tom and Nick's meeting in the Great Gatsby

Tags: character-analysis, meaning, the-great-gatsby, f-scott-fitzgerald

At the end of Gatsby when Tom and Nick meet, after their conversation Nick states that Tom:

> "went into the jewelry store to buy a pearl necklace — or perhaps only a pair of cuff buttons — rid of my provincial squeamishness forever."

I have a few questions:

- Why didn't Nick tell Tom it was Daisy, not Gatsby in the car. (and does Tom already know that)?
- Why does Nick say he is: (My friend told me it has something to do with character but I don't understand it)

  > "rid of my [his] provincial squeamishness forever."
- What is the significance of Tom walking into a jewelry store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Nick did not tell Tom that Daisy was driving because then Myrtle's husband would have gone after Daisy instead of Gatsby. I also believe that Gatsby asked Nick not to tell anyone that it was Daisy driving to avoid any legal or moral trouble.
2. Tom going into the jewelry store may show that Tom is over Gatsby and is now focusing on the materialistic side of the 1920s and his wealth. There's a quote that states "They were careless people, Tom and Daisy – they smashed up things and creatures and then retreated back into their money or their vast carelessness, or whatever it was that kept them together, and let other people clean up the mess they had made…". So perhaps this meant that Tom did not care anymore and was moving on with his life.